# ps command output, WCHAN column '-' for all processes

Tags: linux, c, ps, scheduling, sleep

`ps axo ppid,pid,stat,wchan,cmd` outputs `-` for the `WCHAN` column for all processes, including the ones in sleep, on Debian bullseye, did I do something wrong?

BTW, `wchan` shows 'the kernel function in which the process is sleeping', according to man page. What does it mean exactly? The caller of kernel `schedule()/schedule_timeout()`? If so, it sounds like `ps` needs to scan the process kernel stack and kernel symbol table to back out the caller's function name?